# laravel & vuejs - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option. found in

Tags: laravel, vue.js

[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

i am trying to use laravel passport
i followed the process from laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport
but when i launched the page i get the above errors

app.js

```
Vue.component(
'passport-clients',
require('./components/passport/Clients.vue').default
);

Vue.component(
'passport-authorized-clients',
require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue').default
);

Vue.component(
'passport-personal-access-tokens',
require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue').default
);
Vue.component('example-component', 
require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));



const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    data:{
    search: ''
    },
    methods:{
    searchit(){
        Fire.$emit('searching');
    }
    }
 });
```

this is the code from developer.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card card-default">
                    <passport-clients></passport-clients>
                    <passport-authorized-clients></passport-authorized-clients>
                    <passport-personal-access-tokens></passport-personal- 
               access-tokens>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i solve it by removing the ".default" from the end of the components

Answer (score 4):

removing the ".default" from the end of the components save my day.

Answer (score 1):

After changing app.js file you had to run this code for solve this error:

```
npm run dev
```

Or:

```
npm run watch
```